# how to apply bug fixes on open source wso2 API Manager 4.0.0 and wso2 Micro Integrator 1.2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-micro-integrator

We are working on WSO2 Open source API Manger 4.0.0 and Micro Integrator 1.2.0. we need to apply the bug fixes. We are unable get the latest build of specific WSO2 API Manager and Micro Integrator versions from the source code.

We are trying to get latest build by building the product from source code available in below github. But the master branch contains latest APIM and MI versions. could you please help on build the product of specific APIM and MI versions (APIM 4.0.0 and MI 1.2.0)

API Manager:
https://github.com/wso2/product-apim

Micro Integrator:
https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator

Answer (score 0):

You can checkout from the tag and apply the fixes.

https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v4.0.0

https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator/tree/v1.2.0

Carbon APIMGT version for APIM v4 - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/tree/v9.0.174

Carbon APIMGT contains the core functionalities of the product APIM.

Answer (score 0):

WSO2 API Manager and MI are a collection of different jars and webapps. In our opensource code base, each product has a product repo ([product-apim](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim), [micro-integrator](https://github.com/wso2/micro-integrator), [product-is](https://github.com/wso2/product-is)) and multiple component repositories ([carbon-apimgt](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt), [wso2-synapse](https://github.com/wso2/wso2-synapse)). All of these are in the [WSO2](https://github.com/wso2) or [WSO2-extensions](https://github.com/wso2-extensions) organization.

If you want to find the codebase for a specific version of a product or a component, you can check the release tag of the repository. For an example, if you want to find the APIM 4.0.0 related code base, you first need to get the 4.0.0 [tag](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/tree/v4.0.0) in product-apim repository.

Since we use maven as the build tool, [pom.xml](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v4.0.0/pom.xml) in the product repository includes all the component versions. Most of the time, fix is sent to a component repository and you can find the relevant component version by referring to this pom.xml. For example, most of the apim specific components are included in the carbon-apimgt repository. You can find the relevant carbon-apimgt version in the pom.xml as [9.0.174](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v4.0.0/pom.xml#L1270).

If you check out the carbon-apimgt repo's 9.0.174 tag, you can find the relevant code base. Similarly, synapse version is [2.1.7-wso2v227](https://github.com/wso2/product-apim/blob/v4.0.0/pom.xml#L1341).

Once you find the relevant code base, you can apply your fix and build the component locally. This will build the jar with your fix and you can patch the product by adding this jar to the /repository/component/patches/patch0001/<Jar_name>.jar.
Make sure that use the same name as the jar included in the /repository/component/plugins repository (Sometimes the "-" in the name is converted to "_" in the name).